# Event Handling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to JavaScript and currently learning basics of DOM with event handling.
This is my HTML Code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>My Test Program for Event Handler</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>The first captain of the USS Enterprise NCC-1701 was
<a id="t1" href="http://en.wikipedia.org/">My Link!</a>.</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="example.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And, this is my Jscript:-

```
var StrayClickCatcher = {
    init: function () {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        if (typeof document.addEventListener != "undefined") {
            document.addEventListener("click", StrayClickCatcher.strayClickListener, false);
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                links[i].addEventListener("click", StrayClickCatcher.linkClickListener, false);
            }
        } else if (typeof document.attachEvent != "undefined") {
            document.attachEvent("onClick", StrayClickCatcher.strayClickListener);
            for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                links[i].attachEvent("onClick", StrayClickCatcher.linkClickListener);
            }
        }
    },
    strayClickListener: function (event) {
        alert("Did you mean to click a link? " + "It's that blue, underlined text.");
    },
    linkClickListener: function (event) {
        if (typeof event == "undefined") {
            event = window.event;
        }
        if (typeof event.stopPropagation != "undefined") {
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    }
};
```

I want to show an alert message when user doesn't click on the link. But, its not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: For the love of god, indent your code properly. It's an unreadable mess.

Comment: Did you call StrayClickCatcher.init() from somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working if you call

```
StrayClickCatcher.init();
```

at the end of your js code. Here is a working copy:

http://jsfiddle.net/DaHHP/

Comment: Ahh.. The missing part! Thanks.